# Extract first and last element of path data type in Postgres?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Our postgres database has tables that have a "path" data type consisting of a list of points that make up a line. Is there any way in postGIS or postgres to extract the first and last coordinate pairs from each entry? The purpose is to determine the cardinal direction of each line using [ST_Azimuth](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Azimuth.html), but that function requires the coordinates of the first and last point.

I've tried every way I can think of, but the path data type doesn't act like a string or an array, so it's difficult to pull out items from it.

Comment: There is no path data-type. It's `LINESTRING`. just an fyi. ;)

Comment: [This](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6600) is what I'm referring to. Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: No. that has nothing to do with PostGIS, and it's terrifying that you're using that. That's the native PostgeSQL path type.

Comment: I'm new to PostGIS! I'm just going off of what I know in my postgres server.

Comment: If you're using path then you're *not* using PostGIS. At least there.

Comment: can you update your question `\d table` (run it in psql)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure there's any direct way to extract points from the `path`.  You can see a list of functions for the `path` datatype with:

```
SELECT proname 
FROM pg_proc, pg_type
WHERE typname = 'path' AND pg_type.oid = ANY(proargtypes);
```

This list does show a `geometry` function that converts between the PostgreSQL `path` type and the PostGIS `LineString` type.  I don't see this function in the PostGIS docs anywhere, but it is apparently available since version 2.1.  With this function, you can call PostGIS functions on your `path` data:

```
WITH data AS (VALUES (path '[(0,0),(1,1),(2,0)]'), (path '[(3,3),(2,7)]')) 
SELECT ST_Azimuth(
    ST_StartPoint(geometry(column1)), 
    ST_EndPoint(column1::geometry))
FROM data;
```

Since the `geometry` function is a casting function, you can use either the `geometry(column1)` or `column1::geometry` syntax.

You might consider storing your geometry in the PostGIS `geometry` type, which has a lot more functionality than `path` type at the expense of a 24-byte overhead per geometry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ST_StartPoint`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_StartPoint.html) and [`ST_EndPoint`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_EndPoint.html)

```
SELECT ST_StartPoint(geom), ST_EndPoint(geom)
FROM tbl;
```